# QT to Core wallet

Tags: transactions, wallet

I have Bitcoin core wallet synced, my original wallet was bitcoin QT version 0.7. My Bitcoin QT wallet never synced and i tried receiving my bitcoins. Now that bitcoin core has synchronized how do I transfer my transaction to bitcoin core?

Answer (score 1):

Normally both bitcoind and bitcoin-qt use the same wallet and blockchain data. So you should just be able to shut down one and start the other.

Comment: Ok, so if the transaction wasnt completed on the bitcoin-qt wallet do i try to redo the transaction on my bitcoin core wallet? Thank you

Comment: I tried opening my bitcoin-qt wallet and it will no longer open @Jannes

Comment: @kym You're not giving a whole lot of information there and this site is not really meant for back and forth trouble shooting. You might get lucky googling for your symptoms or maybe go on one of the forums (reddit/r/bitcoin or bitcointalk) or IRC #bitcoin for troubleshooting.